# Order Item detail In custom Email template

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom Email template in which i need to show default Order item detail. I have created a template in the admin using

```
Marketing->email templates
```

and this email is triggered with a custom action. That custom action is created in custom module.
i am trying to get the order_item value by using

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

But i am not getting any Order related data into me email.

Comment: How are you passing $order to the email templates share that bit of code

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to set in database table: email_template column is_legacy = 1. Below is SQL query. Note:-Replace your tempate_id

```
 UPDATE `email_template` SET  `is_legacy` = '1' WHERE `template_id` = '9';
```